# Machine code finding in arm assembly(branch)

Tags: assembly, arm

hey everyone i am trying to convert below code to machine code but i stucked.."The offset for branch instructions is calculated by the assembler: – By taking the difference between the branch instruction and the target address minus 8 (to allow for the pipeline)."Found tihs info in some slides.According to this information I assume 1. line's adress is ...4000 and BNE loop's address in 400c.So 4000-400c=-c and -c-8=-14.So i thought machine code value should be 0001 101 0 111111111111111111101100.The last part is offset and its -14's 2's cmplemen.Is it true i cannot sure?But also some resources says offset value should be -5 so i can not sure.
[this is the empty set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfUKF.png)

```
loop LDR R2,[R1],#4 ; Loading value from array and ;updating(increment) the address
ADD R3,R3,R2 ; Sum is stored in R3 register
SUB R0,R0,#1 ; Decrementing counter value
CMP R0,#00 ; Checking counter value
BNE loop
```

Comment: If `loop` is at `4000` then `BNE` can not be at `400c`. It's at `4010`. The offset is in words not bytes, it is thus -6 words. The encoding is `1A FF FF FA`. You can check this using an assembler yourself.

Comment: Sorry i am new at this.i couldn't understand how it is -6.

Comment: 4 instructions to jump back (`CMP` + `SUB` + `ADD` + `LDR`), plus 2 for the pipeline (the 8 bytes are 2 words/instructions). Or if you want to count using the addresses then `0x4000 - 0x4010 - 8 = -24 bytes = -6 words`

Comment: oh got it.thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
00002000 <loop>:
    2000:   e4912004    ldr r2, [r1], #4
    2004:   e0833002    add r3, r3, r2
    2008:   e2400001    sub r0, r0, #1
    200c:   e3500000    cmp r0, #0
    2010:   1afffffa    bne 2000 <loop>
```

assembled and linked.

1afffffa  condition 0b0001, 0b1010 opcode, branch (not link)  signed immediate 24

0xFFFFFA

```
<target_address>
Specifies the address to branch to. The branch target address is calculated by:
1. Sign-extending the 24-bit signed (two’s complement) immediate to 32 bits.
2. Shifting the result left two bits.
3. Adding this to the contents of the PC, which contains the address of the branch
instruction plus 8.
```

so:

```
0xFFFFFFFA<<2 = 0xFFFFFFE8
0xFFFFFFE8+0x2010+8 = 0x2000
```

object disassembly:

```
0xFFFFFFE8+0+8 = 0x0
```

To create the instruction 0x2000 - (0x2010+8) = 0xFFFFFFE8, 0xFFFFFFE8>>2 = 0xFFFFFFFA, trim to 24 bits 0x00FFFFFA.  add in the condition and opcopde 0x1AFFFFFA.

For this kind of stuff, get the original ARM ARM, the closest you can find from ARM without googling for illegal copies, is to get the ARMv5 ARM ARM, and that includes easy to understand descriptions like above.  Sometimes the ARMv7-AR is better but a lot of the time the original ARM ARM direct descendants are the best.